# minimum radius of circle tangent to 3 sides of quad

Tags: geometry, vectors, circles, quadrilateral

I have a convex quadrilateral defined (in counterclockwise order) by the points $$p_0=(x_0,y_0)\\p_1=(x_1,y_1)\\p_2=(x_2,y_2)\\p_3=(x_3,y_3)$$ I want to found the minimum radius between all the radius of circles tangent to 3 edges. In the image below, it's radius r4[image] (more info [here](http://sites.uclouvain.be/slim/assets/files/Seny_UCL_2014.pdf#subsection.2.3.6))

At the moment, I'm thinking of calculating the bisectors, find the point of intersection and projecting that onto an edge and then be able to find the radius... but I'm really not able to find an efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT.

You can compare the sums of opposite sides of your quadrilateral ($p_0p_1+p_2p_3$ and $p_0p_3+p_1p_2$): the two sides with the greater sum are both touched by the minimum circle. The center of the circle must then belong to the bisector of those two sides.

Comment: Wow that's huge :-) Isn't the circle an excircle of the triangle formed by the extension of those two sides and the smallest remaining side?

Comment: Yes: those two sides form an angle and you want the excircle of the triangle formed by the angle and the side nearer to the angle vertex. If the sides are parallel then no triangle is formed, but in that case both circles touching the sides have the same radius.

Comment: Ok. As I want to find the value of the radius, it helps me a lot because the formula for the radius of the excircle is quite easy and it fits really well in my code. I will edit the question to include my complete answer. Thanks you very much !